# first pair of the same symbols

Tags: python, for-loop

Find the first (consecutive) pair of the same symbols using for-loop. It doesn't matter if there are more than 2 same consecutive symbols.

Example:

"abBcccc" returns "cc"

What I have so far:

```
result = []
    for c in range(len(text) - 1):
        if text[c] == text[c + 1]:
            result.append(text[c])
    print("".join(result))
```

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: You have `for c in text:` and then `if c == c + 1:` but `c` is "a", "b", "B", etc so adding one to those letters is not correct here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using iterators with index seems to be the only way here:

```
string = "abBcccc"

for index in range(0, len(string)-1):
    if string[index] == string[index+1]:
        print(string[index:index+2])
        break
```

It's needed to break to only get the first one.